Why does fission of large nuclei always result in energy released?
When large nuclei undergo fission, the binding energy per nucleon of products is greater than the binding energy of the original nuclei. This only happens (with certainty) when the products are Iron-56 or more though.
Sometimes the products aren't always larger than iron. Here's an example of neutrons being produced. I think I've also read somewhere that hydrogen can possibly be produced. Both of them have 0 binding energy per nucleon. Doesn't such products bring down the overall average binding energy per nucleon of the products?
$$^{236}\text U\to {}^{90}\text{Sr}+ {}^{143}\text{Xe} +3n$$
So my question is: is it possible the average binding energy per nucleon of the products is less than that of the original nucleus? In other words, that a fission of a heavy nuclei requires energy to proceed instead of releasing energy?

Not all heavy nuclei will spontaneously fission.

I am reticent to make a comment that applies to all nuclei. Given a reaction, just look at the initial mass and the final mass of the nuclei.

For the complementary reason that fusing small nuclei (sub -iron) releases energy.  It's all about the net nuclear force behavior amongst the particles contained in a nucleus.

@JEB thank you. I think this is the clearest answer

Yes. There are cases where nuclear fission reaction is endothermic rather than exothermic. These occur on fissioning of small nuclei.
An example would be Lithium-7 absorbing a high energy neutron (>2.47 MeV) and fissioning into Helium-4, Tritium and release an neutron:
$_3^7Li+n\rightarrow_2^4He+_1^3H+n$
This is endothermic. It occurs in some thermonuclear bombs to increase their explosive power. It was first noticed in the Castle Bravo tests.
There may also be other endothermic fission reactions involving uranium and transuranic elements, especially in excited states, but they are highly impractical and thus have never been documented.
Fission of large nuclei are otherwise exothermic as the resulting products have higher nuclear binding energy, and there is a mass deficit which is compensated by release of energy. These products have higher atomic number than Iron, whose most common isotope Iron-56 has highest nuclear binding energy of all nuclei.

I'm not convinced of your defining Lithium-7 as "special case", since fusing small nuclei is exothermic, so by conservation of energy all fissioned small nuclei are endothermic.

@CarlWitthoft yes that is right. Thank you for the corrections

Thank you the answer. My question was quite hypothetical and probably would not have reason to be induced anyways. But if you look at your equation (or mine), neutrons (which have zero binding energy) are released, and I was just wondering if it were possible to release that many neutrons (or small nuclei) such that the overall mass increases.
